# Uniform distribution inside Log

Tags: uniform-distribution, notation, logarithm

What is the meaning of putting uniform distribution inside log? See page 5 of this paper (Corentlin et al.)

[image]

To make it more clearer, within my knowledge, I think I should put a single value inside log(). I have no idea what is the meaning that put a distribution inside. Does it result in another distribution? It's strange to me because I think the author want to get a single value.

It seems like this is really an easy question but I just can't figure it out, and I keep finding log-uniform on internet, which I believe it's not.
Thanks in advance!

## *References*

[Corentin Tallec, Yann Ollivier. Can Recurrent Neural Network Warp Time? *ICLR 2018*](https://openreview.net/forum?id=SJcKhk-Ab)

Comment: 1. This is explicitly discussed in the first sentence on page 5. 2. Please give a full reference and some context for the problem being discussed, not just a link.

Comment: @Glen_b I don't see how the first sentence on page 5, "Values of..." would explicitly discuss the meaning of this notation. But I agree a full reference to the paper is appropriate

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this community. I have edited my post, please check.

Comment: Why do you believe it's not log uniform?

Comment: @Juho It explains why there's a log in the expression in the question.

Comment: @PeterFlom Because I think the author wants to get a single value, so I think it's not log uniform. However, maybe it is......?

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat informal notation, but it cannot have any other meaning than a random variable which is minus the log of a uniform random variable.